# How can I read xlsx file with luacom?

Tags: excel, lua, luacom

I have following code

```
excel = luacom.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 pcall(excel.Open, excel, "1.xlsx")
if excel ~= nil then
    sheets = excel.Worksheets
    sheet1 = sheets:Item(1)

    for row=1, 30 do

      for col=1, 30 do
        local cellValue = sheet1.Cells(row, col).Value2
        if cellValue ~= nil then
            --print(cellValue)

        end
      end
    end
end
```

How can I modify it in order to be able to read the excel file, cause currently excel variable does not hold any workshett, and seemd like the loading did not went well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the Open function call wrong. Try this:

```
local workbook = excel.Workbooks:Open("1.xlsx")
```

Then use the workbook (not excel) to do the rest, for example:

```
local sheet = workbook.Sheets(1)
```